# Calling a method that accepts an optional error pointer

Tags: pointers, macruby

I'm trying to call a method in MacRuby that's defined like this:

```
NSPropertyListSerialization
---------------------------
+ (id)propertyListWithStream:(NSInputStream *)stream
    options:(NSPropertyListReadOptions)opt
    format:(NSPropertyListFormat *)format
    error:(NSError **)error
```

The last argument has to be a pointer, so I'm doing this:

```
err = Pointer.new '@'

data = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithStream plist,
  options: KCFPropertyListMutableContainers,
  format: KCFPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0,
  error: err
```

However, I get this error:

```
expected instance of Pointer, got `200' (Fixnum) (TypeError)
```

The stack trace comes from the `error: err` line.

This error is the same **regardless of the type of the object** passed as `error`. It can be nil, a Pointer, a string or a completely arbitrary type, the error stays the same.

I have **no idea** where `200` fixnum comes from. Certainly not my code (there is barely any more code in this script than what I pasted).

---

**Update:** Solved with the help of @whitequark and @alloy. This was for editing Safari bookmarks in iOS Simulator. You can see [how to read/write binary plist files here](https://github.com/mislav/dotfiles/blob/f915020/bin/simulator_bookmarks#L61-78)

Comment: Forgot to add: MacRuby 0.10 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]

Comment: Just guessing, as I never ever used MacRuby: stacktraces for multiline statements always refer to the last line (i.e. if the error is not caused by a locateable subexpression), and fixnum 200 is one of the constants `KCFPropertyList*`. Can you `p` them?

Comment: Zomg you're right. My problem isn't the `err` object. It was that "format" accepts a pointer but I gave it the value of a constant, which was 200. Please add an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacktraces for multiline statements always refer to the last line (i.e. if the error is not caused by a locateable subexpression), and fixnum 200 is one of the constants beginning with `KCFPropertyList`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the contents of the plist, you should be able to read it with: `NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile(path)`.

Comment: This particular binary plist is actually an Array of Hashes, so `NSArray.arrayWithContentsOfFile(path)` works, thanks. However this approach is only useful when the structure of data inside the plist is known in advance.